# MXNET build model error on r

Tags: mxnet

When I try to use mxnet to build a feedforward model it appeared the following error:

> Error in mx.io.internal.arrayiter(as.array(data), as.array(label), unif.rnds,  : 
>     basic_string::_M_replace_aux

I follow the R regression example on mxnet website but I change the data into my own data which contains 109 examples and 1876 variables. The first several steps can run without error until ran the model building step. I just can't understand the error information mean. I wonder that it is because of my dataset or the way I deal with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the code snippet you are using? That gives more details on the issue. Also, any stacktrace will be useful.

You get this error message mainly due to invalid column/row access and shape (dimension) mismatch. Can you verify if you are using correct "index" values in creating matrix. Let me know if this fixes the issue.

However, MXNet can be better at printing details about error in the stacktrace. I have created a issue to follow up on this - https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/issues/4206